# AlarmManager: problemas con set y cancel

Tags: java, android, método

Estoy comenzando a crear un activity para gestionar alarmas para una aplicación. El problema es que al introducir los métodos set y cancel me dice "Cannot resolve symbol 'set'" y "Cannot resolve symbol 'cancel'" respectivamente.
A ver si alguien puede ayudarme con esto.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

    AlarmManager alarms=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    int alarmType = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
    long time = 10000;
    String ALARM_ACTION = "ALARM_ACTION";
    Intent intentToFire = new Intent(ALARM_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentToFire,0);

    //Set
    alarms.set(alarmType, time, pendingIntent);

    //Cancel
    alarms.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: ¿El `set` y el `cancel` están dentro de un método?

Comment: No, set y cancel son dos métodos de la librería AlarmManager @HectorSeguro

Comment: Tanto tu código como los import son correctos, te aconsejo agregar tu build.gradle! @Androidvsmi